# Remove only 3 characters after a specific string

Tags: php, regex, string, url

Hi I have this string for example

```
http://aaa-aaaa.com/bbbb-bbbbbbbbbb-2/it/clients/
```

I want to remove only 3 characters after `bbbb-bbbbbbbbbb-2/`, so basically I want to remove the `it/` part (This `it/` part may not always be `it` but it can be `es/` or `en/` or different languages always 2 characters )

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `http://aaa-aaaa.com/bbbb-bbbbbbbbbb-2/` - it's hard to say if that pseudo URL is constant. You could probably pull this off with `parse_url()` (*and/or `substr()`*).

Comment: @u_mulder  str_replace("it/'',"",$url); this removes the it, but this it can change so it doesn't work all the times

Comment: @Fred -ii- Yes that part is always constant, only the it part changes

Comment: So result should be `http://aaa-aaaa.com/bbbb-bbbbbbbbbb-2/clients/`?

Comment: @Mohammad Yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to selecting target part of string and run it in [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$url = "http://aaa-aaaa.com/bbbb-bbbbbbbbbb-2/it/clients/";
echo preg_replace("@(.*)\w{2}/([^/]+/)$@", "$1$2", $url);
```

See result of code in [demo](https://3v4l.org/piPNF)

Answer (score 1):

The following will work provided the the URL structure doesn't change. I assume you're wanting to remove the language part of the URL.

```
<?php

$url = "http://aaa-aaaa.com/bbbb-bbbbbbbbbb-2/it/clients/";

$parsedURL = parse_url($url);
$path = explode('/', $parsedURL['path']);
unset($path[2]);
$url = "{$parsedURL['scheme']}://{$parsedURL['host']}";
$url .= implode('/', $path);

var_dump($url);
// string(47) "http://aaa-aaaa.com/bbbb-bbbbbbbbbb-2/clients/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your languages in an array. If a language is not defined in the array URL will be the same.

```
$mLanguages = ["en","it","bg","gr"];

$mURL = "http://aaa-aaaa.com/bbbb-bbbbbbbbbb-2/it/clients/";

$mURL = removeLanguageFromURL($mURL, $mLanguages);

echo $mURL; // Output http://aaa-aaaa.com/bbbb-bbbbbbbbbb-2/clients/

function removeLanguageFromUrl($mURL, $mLanguages){

    foreach($mLanguages as $language){ // Search languages

        if(strpos($mURL, $language) !== false) // If language is found in url remove it
            $mURL = str_replace('/' . $language,'', $mURL);

    }

    return $mURL;

}
```